# Queries gaining by adding a new index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, optimization, table

How would i be able to find out which queries would gain by adding a new index.

Ex: Lets assume i add a new NCI on a table , how would i be able to find out which queries would benefit from adding this NCI( or any Index ) for that matter of fact?

Comment: Usually you solve this problem in the other direction.  Identify queries that need to go faster and then build an index that will help that query.  You can use sp_blitzindex (Brent Ozar) to help identify potentially missing indexes but without a definable problem to fix, I wouldn't add indexes.  Keep in mind that minor changes to an existing index can make it suitable for multiple queries, and it's possible for an index to make things worse, or not be used by the engine for a number of reasons.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan ...but here in my case , our production DBAs just handed over a list of Missing indexes and asked us to take a look at this, so i wanted to find out which queries would benefit from these.

Comment: I'd push back, trying to find out why they think the missing indexes need to be applied.  If it's for no reason other than they hate seeing missing indexes then they need to do better.  Did they at least include the optimizers estimate of improvement?  The only thing I can think of is to look at the tables that the missing indexes apply to and then see if you can identify queries/views/procedures that use those tables.  Are you the developer of the application?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the response on this im working with the Prod DBAs to get this solved.. I appreciate your quick response on this .

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Jonathan's comments. There are many resources (to show the DBAs)showing that automated "missing indexes" analysis is very limited and often misleading.

In addition to sp_blitzindex, if you get them to run the following query against each database (after a representative uptime), you can get an idea of which tables are the cause of possibly unnecessary IO due to high number of scans (considering the row counts) and lookups. And you can start to consider the indexes suggested just for those tables, and/or find the offending queries and consider indexing for them.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
SELECT  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Schema]
    , OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS [Table]
    , i.name AS [Index]
    , i.type_desc AS [Index Type]
    --, p.partition_number
    , p.rows AS [Row Count],
       USER_SEEKS, 
       USER_SCANS, 
       USER_LOOKUPS, 
       USER_UPDATES
FROM sys.partitions p 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON p.object_id = i.object_id
                         AND p.index_id = i.index_id
left join (select * from SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS  where DATABASE_ID = DB_ID(DB_NAME())) b ON b.object_id = i.object_id and b.index_id = i.index_id 
WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(p.object_id) != 'sys'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to see which procedures are using an specific table, (`and therefore potentially benefiting (or getting worst) from the addition of a missing indexes`)
I have a couple of scripts that might help you:

this first script shows the procedure and the table(s) the procedure uses:

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS (
SELECT 
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
WHERE o.xtype = 'P')
SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

This is a variation of the script above, written in a slightly different way:

```
--another way

/*
      Get the DB Tables used in a Stored Procedure  
      It used from sysdepends, sysobjects table to gather information
      It may not be accurate if the DB is not refreshed

*/

SELECT @@SERVERNAME
      ,DB_NAME()

DECLARE @sp_name SYSNAME

SELECT @sp_name = 'udpDatabaseReindex'

SELECT o.id, o.name as 'Procedure_Name' 
         , oo.name as 'Table_Name'
         --, d.depid
FROM SYSDEPENDS d
     LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSOBJECTS o
                  ON o.id=d.id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSOBJECTS oo
                  ON oo.id=d.depid

WHERE  o.name= @sp_name   -- Stored Procedure Name
GROUP BY o.id
       , o.name 
       , oo.name

ORDER BY o.name
```

You can use the following script by Greg Larsen, to help comparing before and after adding the index.

It measures cpu and I/O.

```
---------------------------------------
-- Greg Larsen
-- Reduced Resource Numbers due to SUM
-- I found another bug in my SQL Server 2005 code for identifying the stored procedure statistics. Here is the fixed code:

SELECT CASE WHEN dbid = 32767 then 'Resource' ELSE DB_NAME(st.dbid)END AS DBName
,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) AS [SCHEMA_NAME] 
,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid)AS [OBJECT_NAME]
,MAX(qs.creation_time) AS 'cache_time'
,MAX(qs.last_execution_time) AS 'last_execution_time'
,MAX(cp.usecounts) AS [execution_count]
,SUM(total_worker_time) / MAX(cp.usecounts) AS AVG_CPU
,SUM(total_elapsed_time) / MAX(cp.usecounts) AS AVG_ELAPSED
,SUM(total_logical_reads) / MAX(cp.usecounts) AS AVG_LOGICAL_READS
,SUM(total_logical_writes) / MAX(cp.usecounts) AS AVG_LOGICAL_WRITES
,SUM(total_physical_reads) / MAX(cp.usecounts)AS AVG_PHYSICAL_READS 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
join sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp on qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
WHERE objtype = 'Proc' 
AND text
NOT LIKE '%CREATE FUNC%' 
GROUP BY cp.plan_handle,DBID,objectid;
```